# ember-data RESTAdapter creates a duplicate record in the store

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Duplicate record creation in store when using RESTAdapter.

Project is using EAK with the following dependencies:

ember "~1.4.0" and 
ember-data "~1.0.0-beta.7”

Source creates a duplicate record in the store.  But not on the server?

```
        var newReservation = this.store.createRecord('reservation', {
            "roomId": roomId,
            "hotelId": hotelId,
            "price":  price,
            "checkInDate":  searchCriteria.checkInDate,
            "checkOutDate":  searchCriteria.checkOutDate
        });

        var self = this;
        newReservation.save().then(function() {
            // Success
            self.transitionToRoute('confirmation');
        }, function() {
            // error
        });
```

The server api-stub responds and provides me with a record that includes the id or primary key.  Its the record I really care about.  So why the dup?

Is createRecord being called twice?  If so, how can we avoid this?

Thanks,

VJ

Comment: What's the response being sent back by the server on save, and why do you say there's a dupe?

Comment: The response is a JSON representation of the record reservation (that includes the id or primary key).  Its structure is identical to what was used to create the original record for the  ember store.  It just didn't have an id.  The server provides the id from the persistence mechanism.

Comment: {
id: 1,            "roomId": 4,
            "hotelId": 9,
            "price":  99,
            "checkInDate":  03/04/2014,
            "checkOutDate":  03/06/2014
        }

Comment: The server side says there is one record while the ember.store says two records.

Comment: Its not all the time.  I just tested again and it worked find then I added another reservation and dup showed up.  Two records on the server and three in the client store.

Comment: createRecord may not be firing twice but the store is at times picking up a duplicate record.

Comment: Is that really what the json looks like, is it not `{reservation:{....}}` ?

Comment: And are you looking in the ember extension in chrome to show there is a dupe, or how are you ascertaining there is a dupe?

Comment: RESOVLED.  It was a server side issue.  The JSON returned incorrect.    The post was returning an array that contained more than the record that was created.  It was my fault.

Comment: Please answer your question below and mark it as answered